# First push is not pushing all files in a big project

Tags: git, push

I have a large project, now disbanded, that I want to push to a Gitea server just for backup purposes.

The project counts about 55000 files and 10GBs!

Now, I initialized the local repository as usual, then

```
git add .
git commit -m "first push"
git push -u origin master
```

The push took hours, but apparently, it finished without errors... but now, from the Gitea web interface I can see it's much smaller: only a few files and directories have been actually pushed.

If I try another commit, git says '*Your branch is up to date with origin/master*'.

I cloned the remote repository into another directory and it counts "only" 3500 files and 800MBs, so something's wrong.

I think the problem is in the project size, but I can't understand why I don't get errors and how I can deal with them.

Comment: Can you try `git status` to see if there are untracked files in your index? Is there anything in your `.gitignore` file?

Comment: `git status --ignored` is what you're looking for. However, you also only pushed the master branch, which may or may not be the right one.

Comment: `git status --ignored` returns nothing... Moreover, this is a new repository, so there is just only the 'master' branch, and there isn't a .gitignore file

Comment: Was your project *already in Git*, or was it in some other VCS or no VCS at all?  If you created a new repository and ran `git add .`, that would add all files at the current working tree and below and your `git commit` would be the first and only commit. You can just take a look at the list of files *in* that first and only commit, using `git ls-tree -r HEAD`, and compare that list of files to what you expect to find.

Comment: This is a brand new repository (no branches, no subrepositories or whatever): it's just old stuff that I want to backup... Anyway, `git ls-tree -r HEAD` returns the files that where actually pushed, so there's something wrong with my commit, but what? It was supposed to include the whole content